# Boss Monster expansion problem

Tags: expansions, boss-monster

I Have both Boss Monster and Boss Monster The Next Level. If I was to combine the two of them would a shuffle all the decks together or is there a maximum number of cards for both decks.

Comment: I don't see how any sensible answer includes more than telling you to read the user manual. Which I assume you've done. Is that correct?

Comment: That I have. My questions lie more a long the lines of if you are to combine all decks together, and if not how do you do it. The room decks and the spell decks I assume are meant to be put together. And in the user's manual it states that games for certain numbers of players are meant to have a certain number of Heroes and epic Heroes but in some of the manuals they also say that the star symbol heros are supposed be auto includes which would then surpass the state of number in the manual. My confusion stems from the vagueness of the rules when it comes to adding expansions.

Comment: Please [edit] the contents of your comment into your question; without it, it's really not clear what you're asking. I thought you were talking about the mobile app version of the game!

Comment: Am I correct in thinking this question is basically "What is the maximum deck size in Boss Monster? (if Any)"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When combining Boss Monster with Boss Monster: The Next Level you still use the standard hero allocations, i.e.

> Two Players: 13 Heroes, 8 Epic Heroes
>   Three Players: 17 Heroes, 12 Epic Heroes
>   Four Players: 25 Heroes, 16 Epic Heroes

But you choose the hero sets from either two packs. For example, you can use the regular Heroes from Boss Monster, and the Epic Heroes from The Next Level, or vice-versa.

Heroes marked with a star can then be added on top of those numbers, or used in place of ones marked with the appropriate number of players (the star heroes are mostly promo ones, and are intended to make the game harder/more interesting).

You also combine each of the Spells, Rooms, and Bosses decks from both sets to form larger decks.